# How to use OR in a COUNTIF function when dealing with dates and ">" characters

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, syntax, countif

I want to write a function whereby I could count a cell if it is blank OR greater than a date.

This is a piece in what will be a much larger formula so looking to avoid a solution of SUM(countif(D:D,""),countif(D:D,">"&E1))

The function I have currently looks like this:

Sum((Countifs(D:D,{">"&E1,""}))

Where E1 = 12/1/2015

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`COUNTIFS()` doesn't seem to like mixing array constants and cell references like that. It works fine if you hard-code the date like this:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(D1:D4,{">12/1/2015",""}))
```

Or if you don't want to hard-code it, use this array formula. This formula must be confirmed with ctrl+shift+enter.

```
=SUM(--(D1:D4>E1),--(D1:D4=""))
```

Note that both of these solutions, as well as just `=COUNTIF(D:D,"")` will count *every* blank cell in the column, so you can't select the entire column (unless your data fills the entire column).

Comment: It isn't that `COUNTIFS` doesn't like the mixing of array constants and cell references.  It is that an array constant cannot contain a cell reference. Array constants can contain only numbers, text, logical values (such as TRUE and FALSE), and error values ( such as #N/A).

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the required array with a little manipulation, e.g.:

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(D:D,IF({0,1},">"&E1,"")))`

though are you sure you really want to count all blanks within the entirety of column D?

Regards